# Weird line wrapping in terminal with a colored prompt

Tags: terminal, bash

I have reason to think I've got improper escaping in my bash prompt (I get weird random line wrapping in Terminal).

Can anyone point it out? It looks OK to me...

```
export PS1="\033[0;35m\u\033[00m on \033[0;36m\h\033[00m in \033[0;33m\w\033[00m \$ "
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encase your colors in brackets `[]` so they count as [non-printable characters](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/nonprintingchars.html).

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;35m\]\u\[\033[00m\] on \[\033[0;36m\]\h\[\033[00m\] in \[\033[0;33m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ "
```

Unfortunately, this results in well-known line wrapping issues that is plagued by bash.

There is good news everyone, the light at the end of the tunnel is `tput`.

```
echo $(tput setaf 6) This is cyan
```

Set all your variables first, then use it within the script.

```
mg=$(tput setaf 5);cy=$(tput setaf 6);yl=$(tput setaf 3);rs=$(tput sgr0); echo $mg $USER $cy $HOSTNAME $yl $PWD $rs
```

You can find an example script [in my github `dotfiles` repo](https://github.com/jnovack/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/colorize.sh)

Comment: Additional resources:  https://github.com/jnovack/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/colorize.sh